# How should I use transformOrigin in Material UI in Menu component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use Menu from Material UI and I need to move it up once it's open. To do it precisely I want to use `transformOrigin ={{vertical: }}` . My question is how shall I write it properly? I tried different ways of coding it, but it still shows me an error.

Below You can see how it looks when I use built value for :    vertical:'bottom'. It's not covering it fully as I want, thus probably I need to move it manually.

[image]

This is how code looks now:

```js
const StyledMenu = withStyles({
  paper: {
    border: "1px solid #FFFFFF",
    boxShadow:
      "0px 16px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 6px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0px 8px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
    borderRadius: "0px",
    fontSize: "1.3rem",
  },
  list: {
    fontSize: "1.3rem",
  },
})((props: MenuProps) => (
  <Menu
    elevation={0}
    getContentAnchorEl={null}
    anchorOrigin={{
      vertical: "bottom",
      horizontal: "center",
    }}
    transformOrigin={{
      vertical: "bottom",
      horizontal: "center",
    }}
    {...props}
    style={{ fontSize: "1.3rem" }}
  />
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the number based on your menu position.

```
transformOrigin={{
  vertical: -10,
  horizontal: 140,
}}
```